# Reauthenticate on restart - Android

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

I need reauthenticate user credentials every time onRestart is called (usually this means the user has locked&unlocked the screen or put it on background and then returned to it).

So I did that:

```
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setAction(LoginActivity.REAUTHENTICATE);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This works, the LoginActivity was shown, but when it finishes the onRestart of the first Activity is called again and the LoginActivity is opened again.

How can I handle that?

Comment: there should be some variable to get that user is authenticated yet or not ....means some like it's session is valid?

Comment: Dheeresh, there's a flag indicating it, but the client want the user to completely reauthenticate onRestart.

Comment: Using startActivityForResult, the onActivityResult is called before opening the LoginActivity (right after onRestart)

Comment: is current activity has launch mode  Single instance ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I used this to solve it:

```
    private static final int REAUTHENTICATE = 80;

    private boolean authenticated;

    @Override
    public void onRestart() {
        if(authenticated)
            return;

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.setAction(LoginActivity.REAUTHENTICATE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REAUTHENTICATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        authenticated = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == REAUTHENTICATE)
            authenticated = true;
    }
```

Well, this it no what I expected but works, I hope someone find a better solution. Cause onRestart keep getting called after onActivityResult.

Answer (score 1):

Until got a good solution/suggestion from any one can try this .

```
1- Put a boolean variable in shared pref named AuthentacationNeeded
2- get that in OnRestart with default value true 
3-if value is true then only startActivity
4- put that variable true in onpuase 

in Login activity 
4-   put that variable false Before finish()
```

Comment: Well, this should work. But it's a ugly solution, I used another one (not good also)

Comment: I answered this question, that was the solution

Comment: I also suggested that in comment before this but you said  "Using startActivityForResult, the onActivityResult is called before opening the LoginActivity (right after onRestart)" :(

Comment: They did, but without NEW_TASK they dont ^^