# Android Activity Restarts when using camera or gallery intent

Tags: android, android-activity, camera, gallery, restart

-Hi, All
I am working on one project in android where I am trying to set image from gallery or camera for profile photo by clicking on image view.

With the profile photo I have other fields as well.

Now whenever the user opens profile activity and after finishing  loading of the activity if user presses the home key and again he opens the app, I am showing app lock screen in OnRestart ().

**Now the problem which i faced is as below**

while returning from gallery or camera then activity is being restarted so it shows app lock screen there.

What I want to achieve is that whenever user press home screen and again opens the app it should ask for app lock screen. But when user tries to set profile photo it should not ask for app lock screen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reauthenticate on restart - Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144155/reauthenticate-on-restart-android)